# Error when trying to use IF NOT EXIST in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

trying to check if something is in my database, if not then i want to add it, however i keep getting an error:

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'if not exists

here is my simple line:

```
IF NOT EXISTS 
    ( 
    SELECT 1 
    FROM spending_points 
    WHERE ckey = 'philipj'
    ) 
Begin 
    INSERT INTO spending_points (ckey, available_points, total_points)
    VALUES ('philipj', '100', '100') 
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Its better to create a `unique constraint` on `ckey`.

Reason for the error is, `Mysql` does not support `IF NOT EXISTS` syntax you need something like this

```
INSERT INTO spending_points
            (ckey,
             available_points,
             total_points)
SELECT ckey,
       available_points,
       total_points
FROM   (SELECT 'philipj' ckey,
               '100'     available_points,
               '100'     total_points) a
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   spending_points sp
                   WHERE  a.ckey = sp.ckey)
```

Comment: The available_points and total_points should not be included in the where clause of the not exists - assuming that the cKey column is the primary key column of the table and these 2 columns are not part of the key.

Comment: @J.Schmale - yeah didnt check the If condition properly Updated the post

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [on duplicate key](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) to insert the row if it does not exists or update it if it does:

Per your code:

```
INSERT INTO spending_points (ckey, available_points, total_points)
VALUES ('philipj', '100', '100') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ckey = ckey;
```

The above sentence won't do anything if a record with `ckey` exists